# Cluster's BaselineHistory doesn't contain branching point hash of joining node BlT

Tags: ignite

I have Ignite cluster(v2.9.1) of 2 server nodes used as embedded db(Key value) for my Java app. I am using Java to setup Baseline Topology with persistence between them –
When I start a node -

```
ignite.cluster().state(ClusterState.ACTIVE);
ignite.cluster().baselineAutoAdjustEnabled(true);
ignite.cluster().baselineAutoAdjustTimeout(1 * 60 * 1000); // 1min
```

When other node joins –

```
ignite.cluster().setBaselineTopology(topVer);
```

I am hitting an error scenario as below when using a unit program that updates two nodes A(1001) and B(1000) –

1. Node A starts - ignite.cluster().state(ClusterState.ACTIVE).
2. Node B starts – joins cluster. - setBaselineTopology as above
3. After some time. Node A stopped.

- B is still updating. ''' Baseline after 1 min - autoAdjustTimeout'''

4. Now stop Node B.
5. Node A started. '''ignite.cluster().state(ClusterState.ACTIVE).'''

- A is updating.

6. Start node B. It hangs

Error: Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: BaselineTopology of joining node (1000) is not compatible with BaselineTopology in the cluster. BlT id of joining node (3) less than BlT id of cluster (4) but cluster's BaselineHistory doesn't contain branching point hash of joining node BlT (1000). Consider cleaning persistent storage of the node and adding it to the cluster again.

For this environment, since the number of nodes will be always 2 -
Is there a way to create Baseline Topology with static node details beforehand and pass to java api, so Ignite recognizes it and keeps baseline as size as 2, current one online and other offline until it joins. For these nodes if one or both joins, leaves or removed there is no impact to BlT numbers. Also, how to make sure these two nodes are always in BaselineHistory. If so, can you please point to correct direction how do this.

Or may be how to recover / update baseline history problem, so that this issue is not seen.

Comment: Are you sure that you have highlighted every baseline change in this sequence?

Comment: @alamar :
yes you were correct, I had the same code both in node A and node B. During startup ignite.cluster().state(ClusterState.ACTIVE) -> sets up the baseline and since autoAdjust has the timeout for 1 min it was also setting up the baseline. Again same question how to recover from baseline history problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that you have to wipe the offending node's data directories, maybe running it in a stand-alone mode (single node cluster) before that to off-load data from it.

Make sure to not exclude node from baseline topology if you plan to bring it back with data, and certainly to not adjust baseline topology on a segmented server node to include only itself.